# Linux script with curl to check webservice is up

Tags: linux, curl

I have a webservice provided at `http://localhost/test/testweb`

I want to write a script to check if webservice is up with curl

If there a curl parameter given, returns `200 OK` ok true false so that I can use it is if-else block in linux script

Comment: Please do not alter the question and add the answer, from the accepted answer people will know which solution worked.

Comment: I do not understand why you have warned me not to edit question? As far as I know I have not edited it yet.

Comment: You added your solution to the question; I reversed your update.

Comment: Note about the solutions.  Just because you get a 200, doesn't mean success.   Verizon (and other ISP's) can "help" you with their "search assist", which returns a 200 marketing page for down or missing domains.  So if you're testing DNS availability, also grep the response for some unique phrase.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
curl -sL -w "%{http_code}\\n" "http://www.google.com/" -o /dev/null
```

- `-s` = Silent cURL's output
- `-L` = Follow redirects
- `-w` = Custom output format
- `-o` = Redirects the HTML output to `/dev/null`

Example:

```
[~]$ curl -sL -w "%{http_code}\\n" "http://www.google.com/" -o /dev/null
200
```

I would probably remove the `\\n` if I were to capture the output.

Comment: **+1** - excellent use of curl's exhaustive list of command line options.  One addition might be `-I` so that a HEAD method is used rather than GET.  This still verifies that the page can be generated, but saves you a little bit of bandwidth by dropping the body of the HTML output.  (You still want to `-o /dev/null` to avoid spitting out the rest of the headers.)

Comment: Also of note: the `\\n` (escaped backslash) is only required if you're using bash as your shell interactively, but if you put this in a script OR you use tcsh you should use `\n` instead.  This is a quoting issue; the command line works the same in both shells, interactively and in scripts if you use single quotes instead, à la: `'%{http_code}\n'`  Probably best for consistency to use that instead.

Comment: it is great. I have combined your answer with my script that is used to run  a java service and wait until it is up. I have updated my question. Thanks.

Comment: Verizon sends 200 + marketing content for missing DNS entries.  It's called "Search assist"

Comment: if [ $(curl -sL -w "%{http_code}\\n" "http://www.google.com:8080/" -o /dev/null --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 5) == "200" ] ; then echo "OK" ; else echo "KO" ; fi

Comment: How to send web service type like post, get

Answer (score 8):

I use:

```
curl -f -s -I "http://example.com" &>/dev/null && echo OK || echo FAIL
```

> -f --fail          Fail silently (no output at all) on HTTP errors
> -s --silent        Silent mode
> -I --head          Show document info only

Note:
depending on needs you can also remove the "-I" because in some cases you need to do a GET and not a HEAD

Comment: Finally! I knew there has to be some curl option allowing this. Thanks!

Comment: @M.Volf depending on needs you can also remove the "-I" because in some cases you need to do a GET and not a HEAD

Answer (score 6):

Same as @burhan-khalid, but added `--connect-timeout 3` and `--max-time 5`.

```
test_command='curl -sL \
    -w "%{http_code}\\n" \
    "http://www.google.com:8080/" \
    -o /dev/null \
    --connect-timeout 3 \
    --max-time 5'
if [ $(test_command) == "200" ] ; 
then
   echo "OK" ;
else
   echo "KO" ;
fi
```

Comment: I'm getting `test_command` command not found for the `if` statement line

Comment: @JackTheKnife : https://gist.github.com/KrustyHack/10c2bb781ff6e37d171b5d7a2adf709d

Answer (score 0):

That will check the headers via wget `2>&1`pipes the stderr to stdout
`grep` filters
`-O /dev/null` just throws the content of the page

```
if [ "\`wget http://example.org/ -O /dev/null -S --quiet 2>&1 | grep '200 OK'\`" != "" ]; 
then 
   echo Hello; 
fi;
```

I know not curl, but still a solution

Answer (score 0):

I needed a better answer to this, so I wrote the script below.

The fakePhrase is used to detect ISP "Search Assist" adware HTTP resposnes.

```
#!/bin/bash

fakePhrase="verizon"
siteList=(
  'http://google.com'
  'https://google.com'
  'http://wikipedia.org'
  'https://wikipedia.org'
  'http://cantgettherefromhere'
  'http://searchassist.verizon.com'
)

exitStatus=0

function isUp {
  http=`curl -sL -w "%{http_code}" "$1" -o temp_isUp`
  fakeResponse=`cat temp_isUp | grep $fakePhrase`
  if [ -n "$fakeResponse" ]; then
    http=$fakePhrase
  fi
  case $http in
  [2]*)
    ;;
  [3]*)
    echo 'Redirect'
    ;;
  [4]*)
    exitStatus=4
    echo "$1 is DENIED with ${http}"
    ;;
  [5]*)
    exitStatus=5
    echo "$1 is ERROR with ${http}"
    ;;
  *)
    exitStatus=6
    echo "$1 is NO RESPONSE with ${http}"
    ;;
  esac
}

for var in "${siteList[@]}"
do
  isUp $var
done

if [ "$exitStatus" -eq "0" ]; then
  echo 'All up'
fi

rm temp_isUp
exit $exitStatus
```

Comment: ...or you can just switch to Google DNS or OpenDNS and not have to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
curl -o $CURL_OUTPUT -s -w %{http_code}\\n%{time_total}\\n $URL > $TMP_FILE 2>&1
cat $TMP_FILE
```

Comment: we can grep required condition from TMP_FILE